# reset numbering in Word 2010 heading style?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, chapters

I have defined a custom multi-level list to automatically number chapters, sections, subsections, etc. of a large document, where each chapter is a separate file at the moment.  The automatic list works fine, except that it always and ONLY starts at chapter 5.

A screenshot of the dialogue box defining the top level style is below.  It seems to show that by default the numbering always starts at 5, but I can't find any option in the format options to change that number.  When I use the right-click context menu to reset the numbering value it works fine until I re-open the file, at which point it's right back to 5.  Arrrgh!

How can I reset the default start value in the heading style?  I'd prefer not to delete the style and start from scratch, as there are quite a few levels and a few chapters that have already been formatted.  Also, I'm not quite sure how I got it to work the first time -- there was a lot of trial and error and I'm loath to start over.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your document, go to the first Heading 1 entry, select the numbering drop down on the Home bar and choose "Set Numbering Value". Select 1.

Now right-click on the Heading 1 style quick selector and chose the first option that should say "Update Heading 1 to Match Selection".

I think that should do it. You are right though, this has got hellishly more complex!! There doesn't even seem to be a standard style template that uses numbered chapters!

Comment: Thanks Julian, this works!  It looks like I will have to repeat the process for each new chapter as it defaults to whatever value I updated it to the last time, though I suppose it has to start somewhere.  I agree, it is odd that there is no standard chapter style.

Comment: It should update correctly. Make sure that the following chapter headings say "Continue from previous list" when you look in the "Set Numbering Value" dialog. In fact, you may wish instead to try an Outline Numbering scheme. Select for your first chapter then create a new scheme and make sure that it is linked to Heading 1.